# Opencsv import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, csv

Anyone has a clue why I cannot use opencsv?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
```

> eclipse: "The import au cannot be resolved"

Comment: Does maven find the artifact ?

Comment: Do you use a Maven Eclipse plugin ? (such as http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)

Comment: maven finds the artifact and yes, m2e.

Comment: It probably hasn't been added to your classpath. Is the artifact listed in the "Maven Dependencies" Group in the projet explorer ? (or in project properties > Java Build Path (Library Tab)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Eclipse support for Maven is far from perfect and some weird things sometimes happen. First of all, ensure that you're using m2e, at least 1.0 version. Second thing, regenerate Eclipse project files by `Maven -> Update Project Configuration...`. It must work then.

Answer (score 1):

i wrote this code, and my example works without problem.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
</dependency>
```